# Finding inexpensive path that visits all nodes

Tags: java, a-star

I am currently in the process of going through old programming olympiad questions, and found question 5 rather difficult. The problem is based in some category of graph theory and involves computing the most inexpensive path and visiting all nodes. Full details can be found here: [problem](http://www.olympiad.org.za/olympiad/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/PO-2012-R1-Q-paper-final-v-2012-07-12.pdf)

Would it be suitable to use A* search algorithm? What kind of algorithm would you use to solve the problem, which is fast to implement and can solve the problem in the given time period?

Comment: A* is heuristic, and is not guaranteed to give the shortest path

Comment: Would be better on http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @thomasfedb: ...No, it is perfectly on-topic for this site (though I don't disagree with closing, since it's a very poor question).

Answer (score 1):

As @kiheru stated, A* won't work.

This is the traveling salesman problem, and it's an NP Complete problem. Replace tolls for distance traveled, and you get the same problem. The Traveling Salesman link has several of such algorithms.

[Traveling Salesman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem)

You'll find different algorithms depending on the number of cities, but it gets much more computationally expensive as you add cities to where a computer isn't the best choice for an exact solution.  There are many different techniques for getting an approximation, but it's not a solvable problem.

If I were to code it, I'd use something called [Linguistic Geometry](http://www.stilman-strategies.com/bstilman/lgmain.html) (something I learned in grad school).  Basically you treat the nodes as a game board, and you take one step at a time towards the answer you want and evaluate it.  This won't solve it, but it will give you a good approximation in a very short amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as the [travelling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), and is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete).  That means there is no generally-faster method of solving this problem than brute-forcing *(well, there is actually a `O(2^n*n^2)` solution [based on dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms))*.  Since you are dealing with only 6 nodes, which is 6! = 720 total possible paths to check, the simplest solution would be to just try every different ordering of cities and record which is fastest.

*(Also, contrary to @kiheru's comment above, A* is not a heuristic. It **uses** a heuristic, but still finds an exact solution to the shortest-path problem.  However, either way it does not apply to your problem)*